# natbib authoryear error

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I'm getting natbib error:

```
Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

The 'help' says

> Check the bibliography entries for non-compliant syntax, or select author-year Bibtex style e.g. plainnat.

Can someone point out the error in my ways because `apalike` is an author-year style citation, right?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
some text \citep{citekey1} and \citet{citekey2}
\section{Methods}
\bibliography{$HOME/Dropbox/Reference_Library/library}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: And I can add that the same error occurs with different bibliographic styles. Although strangely enough, when I used jponew from [here](http://www-pord.ucsd.edu/~sgille/how_to/proposal_prep.html) it worked flawlessly the first time but not subsequently

Comment: I don't get any error (I just used one bib database of mine).

Comment: Two ideas: try deleting the `.bbl` auxiliary file and reprocess your document; if that doesn't help, build a minimal `.bib` file that reproduces the error and add it to your question.

Comment: thank Gonzalo. It seems to work now. I actually didn't realize that "Trash Aux Files" in TexShop wouldn't delete the .bbl along with the .aux. I hope I don't have to do that regularly.

Comment: Malformed entries in `.bib` (e.g. with two commas after the key) will lead to this error, which is admittedly confusing.