# Where are the .bbl files located?

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to follow advice at [natbib authoryear error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52776/natbib-authoryear-error) , I don't know where .bbl is. It's not in the working directory.

Comment: Please register on the site so you can comment on posts and interact with the community.

Comment: You *are* using LyX, correct? The `.bbl` should be in the working folder where your `.tex` (or `.lyx`) is located.